# Slightly modified options framework Colour picker

Tags: theme-options, options

I'm using slightly modified options framework for a theme I'm working on, I have used this before with other themes but never had a need to use the colour picker.

I need to be able to allow the user to change the colour of the navigation bar. this is what I have done so far.

**functions.options.php**

```
$of_options[] = array(  "name"      => "Navigation Color",
                    "desc"      => "Pick a background color for the theme (default: #fff).",
                    "id"        => "nav",
                    "std"       => "",
                    "type"      => "color"
            );
```

**footer.php**

```
.nav { background-color:<?php print $smof_data['nav']; ?>; }
```

Have I just missed something completely?

Comment: is this within a `style` tag (which technically is invalid outside the `head` tag, but should work)? do you see the correct data appear when viewing page source? does your browser's inspector see this rule, and is it perhaps being overridden by something more specific?

Comment: It was my fault. fixed it